# Employing elegance in order to evade importing elephants: a case of excessive dll Imports

Tags: c#, marshalling, dllimport, graphic

I am writing C# code that interfaces to a legacy (Feb 2012) C program, using DllImport.   It works fine, but I need to call more than 30 different functions, turning my normally impeccable, exquisite code into something of near-elephantine proportions.  Surely there must be a way around this?  [Warning: those with weak stomachs may want to avert their eyes from what follows]:

```
    [DllImport("C:\\Users\\mitt\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\mrSolution\\mr\\x64\\Debug\\mrDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern bool mrEngine_initialize(     [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] PLOT_SPEC PlotSpec);
    [DllImport("C:\\Users\\mitt\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\mrSolution\\mr\\x64\\Debug\\mrDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern bool mrEngine_getDataPoint(   [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] PLOT_SPEC PlotSpec);
```

Comment: I haven't done much when it comes to interfacing with external DLLs like this, but from what I've gathered it's (generally) OK to have code like this but the class that contains this would really only be a low level bridge.  Write classes that abstract/hide this into a design that makes sense so your consuming code doesn't know/care/suffer about it.  I'm not sure if that's the exact issue you're having or if that's the solution, so I'll just leave it as a comment.

Comment: +1 to Chris's comment above. As another possible suggestion, if it's the P/Invoke nature of the glue that's bothering you, you could also consider writing your glue code in C++/CLI. I'd also echo Chris's sentiment that even if you do so, you still abstract this glue code so it's self-contained...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fairly inevitable with a C style api.  The Windows api being a prime example of one with *thousands* of functions.  Tying them together with handles.  With the handle being the C style equivalent of *this*, the object reference for a class object.

The next leg up is a COM interface, it allows building an object model.  Very common in Windows apis, looks like you lost out on that one.

This however doesn't stop you from creating your own object model, using C# classes whose methods and properties map in a logical way to the underlying C style api.  The fugly code that implements your class members and makes the pinvoke calls can be hidden in a #region that you hopefully never have to look at again.

There is more than one benefit to doing it this way.  Thinking about the object model mapping *really* helps you to understand the underlying api.  And gives you plenty of unit test extension points.  And makes you feel *really* good about creating order out of chaos.

Answer (score 0):

Try to just reference the dll in your project. Sometimes it just works and Visual Studio does all the plumbing for you. If Visual Studio complains for some reason, try to use the tool [TblImp.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). It creates a wrapper that you can reference in your project.

Answer (score 0):

[DllImport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) has a restriction that makes it applicable only to methods. Although it can get ugly,  it is **quite simple** and truly reflects it's intent.

There are two things that come to my mind right now:

1. Use a partial class and split your imports into multiple files. It will make each file smaller and won't hurt your eyes;
2. Use [T4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) to generate the class that contains the imports and forget about it's existence.